# Trie implementation using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, trie

I've implemented a basic Trie that is supposed to work only with lowercase English letters.

```cpp
class TrieNode {
public:
    array<shared_ptr<TrieNode>, 26> children;
    bool isWord;

    TrieNode(bool _isWord = false) : isWord{_isWord} {
    }
};

class Trie {
public:
    Trie() : root{make_shared<TrieNode>(TrieNode())} {
    }
    
    void insert(const string& word) {
        auto p = root;
        for (const auto& ch : word) {
            const auto idx = ch - 'a';
            if (p->children[idx] == nullptr) {
                p->children[idx] = make_shared<TrieNode>(TrieNode());
            }
            p = p->children[idx];
        }

        p->isWord = true;
    }
    
    bool search(const string& word, bool prefix = false) {
        auto p = root;
        for (const auto& ch : word) {
            const auto idx = ch - 'a';
            if (p->children[idx] == nullptr) {
                return false;
            }

            p = p->children[idx];
        }

        if (prefix) {
            return true;
        }
        return p->isWord;
    }
    
    bool startsWith(const string& prefix) {
        return search(prefix, true);
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<TrieNode> root;
};
```

Is the use of `shared_ptr` appropriate here? Could I get more efficiency from this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`

You are never sharing your `std::shared_ptr`s, so it is much better to use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead. `std::unique_ptr` uses less memory and is more efficient.

## Call `std::make_unique()` without arguments

When you call

```
p->children[idx] = make_shared<TrieNode>(TrieNode());
```

The expression `TrieNode()` is creating a temporary `TrieNode` object, and then that is *copied* by `std::make_shared()`. This is unnecessary though, just call `make_shared<TrieNode>()`. Or with `std::unqiue_ptr`:

```
p->children[idx] = make_unique<TrieNode>();
```

## `root` does not need to be a pointer

You can just make `root` be a `TrieNode` directly. Then you can also remove the default constructor.

## Alternative ways to store children

You need some way to allocate memory for children. Your approach of doing something like `std::array<std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>, 26>` is one possible way to do that. However, there are others. The problem with your approach is that every node, even if it is a leaf node, stores 26 pointers. That's 208 bytes on a 64-bit system. It would be nice if you could avoid that, at least for the leaf nodes. So consider this instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::array<TrieNode, 26>> children;
```

Now you only have one pointer (8 bytes on a 64-bit system) in a `TrieNode`, which reduces the memory usage of leaf nodes quite a bit.

There are many other ways to store children; you could use a `std::vector<TrieNode>`, a `std::unordered_map<char, TrieNode>`, or do something completely different. There are tradeoffs between memory usage, performance and easy of programming. Which approach is better also depends on how deep and dense your tries are.

How compact you can store your trie into memory is going to have a big influence on how efficient it will be; the smaller it is the less memory bandwidth will be necessary and the more cache memory will be effective.